# How to count data from another table

Tags: mysql, count, union

I have patient table that has patientnum, patientname
and insurance_cover table that has patientnum,insurancecode

I need to display patient covered with insurance and without insurance, patient number and the total number of insurance,
how will I do that without using join?

```
SELECT 'WITH INSURANCE' AS '',PATIENTNUM, PATIENTSURNAME
from PATIENT where PATIENTNUM 
IN(select PATIENTNUM from INSURANCE_COVER) 

UNION

SELECT 'WITHOUT INSURANCE' AS '',PATIENTNUM, PATIENTSURNAME
from PATIENT where PATIENTNUM 
NOT IN( select PATIENTNUM from INSURANCE_COVER)
```

This code shows data that has with insurance and without insurance..
But I dont know how to count the insurance of patients who have insurance.

Is it right that I use NOT IN?
Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you need summarized info about count of patients with insurance/without it?

Comment: Yes.. I need to have it

Comment: You should add another `UNION` with following `SELECT` containing `COUNT()` and make it look like ie: `WITH INSURANCE AS ''`, `TOTAL AS PATIENTNUM`, `COUNT(...) AS PATIENTSURNAME`

Comment: Should I have 3 UNION?

Comment: One way to do this would be using UNION, so that you will have detailed and summarized results in one table that will be produced by your query. You could also add a 'fake' column containing ID's like 1,2,3,4 and then order by it to get your `SELECT` outputs in desired order.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how can I know how many insurance those patients that have insurance?

Comment: I'm lost at your sentence, sorry. Give me an example, if you could.

Comment: I'll explain it from the start, I have table patient that contains patientnum,patientname. Also I have table insurance_cover that has insurancecode and patientname.. for each patient covered by insurance(s): display the string 'With insurance', the 
patient number, patient name, and the total number of insurances he/she is 
covered by, and 
 for each patient covered by no insurance: display the string 'Without insurance', the 
patient number, patient name, and the total number of insurances he/she is 
covered by (as string ‘Not applicable’).

Comment: I hope I understand you. Added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    'WITH INSURANCE' AS '',
    PATIENTNUM, 
    PATIENTSURNAME,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENT tmp WHERE PATIENTNUM IN(select PATIENTNUM from INSURANCE_COVER) AND tmp.PATIENTNUM = p.PATIENTNUM) AS INSURANCES
FROM
    PATIENT p
WHERE 
    PATIENTNUM IN(select PATIENTNUM from INSURANCE_COVER) 

UNION

SELECT 
    'WITHOUT INSURANCE' AS '',
    PATIENTNUM, 
    PATIENTSURNAME,
    0 AS INSURANCES
FROM
    PATIENT 
WHERE
    PATIENTNUM NOT IN( select PATIENTNUM from INSURANCE_COVER)
```

Comment: this should use UNION ALL and likely to be more efficient using EXISTS or NOT EXISTS

Comment: This is just added line into code that's already been written by it's owner. Since he posted UNION, he should know better what he needs and I don't want to mess with that. We don't know about the size of subquery results, so I wouldn't go that far and start replacing IN with EXISTS since we don't have the entire case.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand. It is simply worth noting that UNION is costlier particularly if it is redundant as it may be here. Similarly I find IN(...) is often overused as it does not scale well and EXISTS was written into the language at inception for this kind of need; I don't see a any reason for not to mentioning it.

Comment: It's good that you have mentioned it - the OP can try&see which option would be better for his plan :) And you are right about that - IN clause is pretty much used all the time, but SO community seems to be advising people to use EXISTS on many occasions.